# The possible length

Tags: geometry

In triangle $ABC$. $AB=5,BC=7$ if we know that the area of the triangle is $14$ then what is the  possible length for $AC$

Answer (score 3):

Set $BC$ as your base. Then the height of your triangle must be 4 since $\frac{1}{2} bh=A$. Then drawing the side with length 5 so that its other end is exactly height 4 this gives you two choices of length for the last side, which you can find easily with Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) ,$$\Delta=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$ where $2s=$perimeter and $a,b,c$ are the sides.

If $AB=c=5,BC=a=7$ and $AC=2d$(say)

So, $$s=\frac{7+5+2d}2=6+d\implies \Delta=\sqrt{(6+d)(6+d-5)(6+d-7)(6+d-2d)}=14$$

$\implies  (6+d)(d+1)(d-1)(6-d)=14^2\implies (6^2-d^2)(d^2-1)=14^2$

$\implies d^4-37d^2+232=0$ which is Quadratic Equation in $d^2$

---

Alternatively using [Law of Cosine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) , $$\cos B=\frac{5^2+7^2-b^2}{2\cdot5\cdot7}=\frac{74-b^2}{70} $$

So, using [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/standard/maths_ii/trigonometry/sin_cosine_area_triangle/revision/3/), $$14=\frac12ac\sin B\implies 28=7\cdot5\cdot \sin B$$
$$\implies \sin B=\frac45\implies \cos B=\pm\sqrt{1-(\frac45)^2}=\pm\frac35$$

So, $$\frac{74-b^2}{70}=\pm\frac35$$

Comment: The answer should be $4\sqrt2$

Comment: @user64388, $b^2=74\pm42=32,126\implies b=4\sqrt2, 3\sqrt{14}$